# How to solve integral equation of convolution using Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, convolution, integral-equations

I'm having trouble solving the following exercise:

Use the Fourier transform to solve the integral equation

$$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x-\xi|}u(\xi)\,d\xi$$

Then verify your solution when $f(x) = e^{-2|x|}.$

My idea was:

Since $F[f(x)] = F[h \ast u(x)] = \sqrt{2\pi} *\hat{h}(k)\hat{u}(k) = \frac{2\hat{u}(k)}{k^2+1}$, then by the Fourier inversion $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 \frac{2\hat{u}(k)}{k^2+1}e^{ikx}dk$.

I'm not sure if this is a correct intuition or not.
Does anyone have some hints?

Comment: The initial idea is correct but shouldn’t you be solving for $u$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I should solve it for u, which should be equal to $F^{-1}(F[f(x)]/F[h(x)])$. Is this all?